# What's the difference of the return type between "def ... = arg.foreach.println()" and "def ... = arg.foreach.println"?

Tags: scala

I accidently type a "()" and the end when I have a code:
`def printList(arg: List[String]) = arg foreach println()`
And it had error when compiling

```
/Users/Edward/Documents/Scala/try/try.scala:75: error: type mismatch
found   : Unit
required: String => ?

def printList(arg: List[String]): Unit = arg foreach println()

                                                        ^
```

But when I change it to 
`def printList(arg: List[String]): Unit = arg foreach println`
It compiles successfully, why does the "()" affects the return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arg foreach println
```

... is syntactic sugar for ...

```
arg.foreach(println)
```

... which is, itself, a simplification of ...

```
arg.foreach(x => println(x))
```

When you type `println()` you are trying to invoke the method with no arguments, which isn't correct.  When you type `println` you are referencing the method without invoking it.  In fact, what you are doing is passing it to the `foreach()` method, which will invoke the `println` after collecting the argument for it.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much.